Not able to connect MySQL 8 on local machine from Talend 6.4
I have installed Talend DI tool for learning purpose but when I try to connect it with MySQL 8 version it showing error "Could not create connection to database server".enter image description here
I have tried to add mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar in "Show View">"Modules">"Import external jars" but its not showing there as well.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
